# Fish shell startup command prints � characters on Hyper

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, fish, hyper

I have the following problem with the fish shell on my mac. I recently figured how to modify the ~/.config/fish/config.fish to automatically run a command upon starting the terminal.

Now, I want to run a particular script that prints some ASCII art, and it works just fine on the regular terminal app (so it shouldn't be a problem with fish or the script, I think) but prints only the � character in the Hyper terminal (Hyper.is). Now the trick is, if I just run the script in the shell, it works just fine.

My question is ; does anyone know why it doesn't work when launched on startup by fish, but works fine when I launch it ?

[image: Screen shot of Hyper.is issue]

Comment: It's better to answer as you did (and accept the answer) than edit the title ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem - I added a very small delay to the script before printing the ASCII art, and now everything works. I think it may be because executing this immediately upon launching of Hyper messed up with a plugin I used (I'm thinking about the hyper full plugin)